# Check constraints on two tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, database-trigger, check-constraints

I have two tables with a one-to-one relationship (and relationship is mandatory from one side only). As follows:

```
create table PRS (
  id number(18) not null,
  common_code varchar2(10),
  constraint pk_prs primary key (id));

create table RLP {
  id number(18),
  spec_code varchar2(20),
  constraint pk_rlp primary key (id),
  constraint fk_rlp_prs foreign key (id) references prs(id) on delete cascade);
```

So the problem is when inserting a record in RLP at least one of `common_code` or `spec_code` must have value.

Is it possible to enforce this constraint using a constraint or the only solution is having a trigger?

Comment: This seems like an odd data model. Why are they two tables? It seems odd that the parent column `prs.common_code` can be null with the "child" column `rlp.spec_code` populated. Those may indeed be the business rules but perhaps there may be a better way of modelling it?

Comment: I use Hibernate as the ORM, and I'm using *joined subclass* method, class PRS has multiple children, each has its own table, and in one of its children (RLP) here, another field exists, and at least one of two code columns must be filled. I can move the `spec_code` to parent class' table, but it does not belong there, and so some database limitations affects the correct data model (which doesn't seem appropriate).

Comment: So a given instance of `prs` can have only one child? If the subclass is `rlp` there can't be another child of subtype `abc`? Are the rules for populating code columns the same for all the subclass tables or does each have its own rules?

Comment: It is a generalization relationship between classes (RLP *extends* PRS), so yes, a PRS has only one child, and if it has RLP, there is no other child of PRS. And no such rule only exists between this only classes.

Comment: Yes. better use triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way to create a constraint on two tables, and the only solution is to create a trigger to throw an exception on desired situation.